# Value of type 'User' has no member 'lowercased'

Tags: ios, swift

I try to create a searcher and which filters the results of every signed up user, but all I get is "Value of type 'User' has no member 'lowercased'" as an error...

The error appears in following line

```
let searchedUser = users.filter({$0.lowercased().prefix(searchText.count) == searchText.lowercased()})
```

Complete code

```
var users = [User]()

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    let searchedUser = users.filter({$0.lowercased().prefix(searchText.count) == searchText.lowercased()})
    searching = true
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

EDIT:
User.swift

```
class User: NSObject {
    var id: String?
    var name: String?
    var email: String?
    var profileImageUrl: String?

    init(dictionary: [String: AnyObject]) {
        self.id = dictionary["id"] as? String
        self.name = dictionary["name"] as? String
        self.email = dictionary["email"] as? String
        self.profileImageUrl = dictionary["profileImageUrl"] as? String
    }
}
```

Comment: What contains in users ?

Comment: Most likely you want to filter something like `$0.name.lowercased()`. And there are better ways to compare case insensitive.

Comment: @vadian is right. Use same code to fix your issue.

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean with just replacing it? I tried it but it seems like I understand you wrong as I just got the same error still

Comment: I wrote my first comment before the *EDIT*. `name` was just a guess. You cannot get the **same** error. The actual error is very descriptive. By the way: Consider to declare `name`, `id` and `email` as non-optional.

Comment: consider declaring your data properties as non-optionals where it makes sense, using empty string as a default, e.g. `id = (dictionary["id"] as? String) ?? ""`.

Answer (score 4):

You have to make one of the **properties** `lowercased` for example `$0.name?.lowercased()`.

But there is a more efficient API to search for a partial string case insensitive and from the start:

```
let searchedUser = users.filter{$0.name?.range(of: searchText, options: [.anchored, .caseInsensitive]) != nil }
```